# How do I draw a marker or a circle on a Google StreetViewPanorama

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view, photosphere

I am creating a walkthrough for the interior of a building and am wondering how to draw a marker on a StreetViewPanorama. Maybe I'm missing something basic, but everything I have read indicates that you need a lat and lng to draw the marker.

Here is what I have:

```
var initPosPanoID, streetView;

    function initPano() {
      // Set StreetView provider.
      var streetViewOptions = {
        zoom: 0,
        panoProvider:  getCustomPanorama,
        pano : "lobby",
        addressControlOptions: {
              position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
        }
      };

      // Create a StreetView object.
      var streetViewDiv = document.getElementById('map');
      streetView = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(streetViewDiv, streetViewOptions);

      // Add links when it happens "links_change" event.
      google.maps.event.addListener(streetView, "links_changed", createCustomLink);

      google.maps.event.addListener(streetView, "pano_changed", function() {
          var panoCell = document.getElementById('pano-cell');
          panoCell.innerHTML = panorama.getPano();
      });

    }

    function getCustomPanoramaTileUrl(panoID, zoom, tileX, tileY) {
      // Return a pano image given the panoID.
      return "images/he/" + panoID + '.jpg';
    }

    function getHeading(panoID) {
          var heading;
          switch(panoID) {
              case "lobby":
                  heading = 0;
                  break;
              case "secorner":    
                  heading = 100;
                  break;
          }
          return heading;
    }

    function getCustomPanorama(panoID) {

      // get a custom heading for the pano
      var heading = getHeading(panoID);

      var streetViewPanoramaData = {
        links: [],
        copyright: 'Imagery (c) HumanElement',
        tiles: {
            tileSize : new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
            worldSize : new google.maps.Size(1024, 512),
            // The heading in degrees at the origin of the panorama
            // tile set.
            centerHeading : heading,
            getTileUrl : getCustomPanoramaTileUrl
         }
      };
      switch(panoID) {
        case "lobby":
          // Description of this point.
          streetViewPanoramaData["location"] = {
            pano: 'lobby',
            description: "Human Element",
            latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(42.282138, -83.751471)
          };
          return streetViewPanoramaData;

        case "secorner":
          streetViewPanoramaData["location"] = {
            pano: 'secorner',
            description: "SouthEast Corner",
            latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(42.282078, -83.751413)
          };
          return streetViewPanoramaData;

      }
    }

    function createCustomLink() {

      var links = streetView.getLinks();
      var panoID = streetView.getPano();

      switch(panoID) {
        case "lobby":
          links.push({
            description : "SouthEast Corner",
            pano : "secorner",
            heading : 280
          });
          break;
        case "secorner":
          links.push({
              description : "HumanElement Lobby",
              pano : "lobby",
              heading : 90
          });
          break;

      }
    }
```

I would like to have different markers or touchpoints at different locations, but am not sure how to get them on there.

Trying to draw a standard marker does not work without the lat/lng.

I thought about trying to create it around a google.maps.Point thinking I might be able to use the x and y from my tiles, but couldn't seem to get that working.

The other options I see are related to google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager.

Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: You do need coordinates (lat/lng) to place a marker on a StreetView.  Why can't you get those coordinates?

Comment: I guess I didn't think I could get them if I am using a custom interior photosphere for my panorama, and not one provided publicly. For example, putting a marker or drawing a circle somewhere on this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-custom-simple

Comment: Note that you can't put a circle on a panorama (at least last I looked), only a google.maps.Marker.

Comment: I suppose i can just use the links changed event and position elements on top of the map though. 

Assuming I know the point, i could probably position the elements from window. 

Has anyone ever done anything like that?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the map this way helped: It creates the map and panorama separately and then sets the panorama into the map, rather than just having the panorama object by itself.

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: position,
            zoom: 10
        });
        // Create the panorama and set it into the map
        panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
            document.getElementById('map'), {
                position: position,
                pov: {
                    heading: 0,
                    pitch: -10
                },
                // Override the default panoId to outside the building to start
                pano:'e_giRekRylYAAAQn7y2xAg'
        });
        map.setStreetView(panorama);
```

For placing markers on the map, I found an excellent plugin which creates points and then places elements on those points.

https://github.com/marmat/google-maps-api-addons/tree/master/panomarker

So far this is working very well. If you have an interior walkthrough, you should be able to toggle markers based on the PanoId. You can even add click listeners to open up dialogs.